# Can't retain array data outside of method in SWIFT

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, swift-playground

I am storing the category name from a JSON in an Array using alamofire .

The array has values only when it is called from this Method `CategoryNameFunc`.

If i call the the array from the tableview or any other method it always `returns 0`

**CODE**

```
    var CategoryNameArray : [String] = []

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            Network()
            tester()
        }

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return CategoryNameArray.count     // This returns 0
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell : UITableViewCell = self.TableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as! UITableViewCell

    println(self.CategoryNameArray[indexPath.row])

    cell.textLabel?.text = "Hello"

    return cell
}


        func Network(){
            Alamofire.request(.GET, "http://www.wive.com/index.php/capp/category_list")
                .responseJSON { (_, _, data, _) in
                    let json = JSON(data!)
                    let count = json.count
                    self.CategoryNameFunc(json, Count: count) }
        }

        func CategoryNameFunc(Json: JSON, Count: Int)
        {
            for index in 0...Count-1 {
                let name = Json[index]["CATEGORY_NAME"].string
                CategoryNameArray.append(name!)
            }
            // This returns 23 (The correct value)
               println(self.CategoryNameArray.count)
        }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and be polite, don't use ! if you need help from others.

Comment: @robertvojta Sorry for that. I have removed it...

Comment: Just replace your println in CategoryNameFunc with self.tableView.reloadData(). To notify tableView about changes - reload.

Answer (score 1):

When you called `Network()` function it creates a new thread (Alamofire start an asynchronous request) and your `tester()` function is not waiting for your `Network()` function to finish before you count your `CategoryNameArray()`.But your `CategoryNameFunc()` function waits for network operation to finish.

Comment: Please Take a look at the Edit

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure (didn't use Almofire) but it think, this happens because the method `Network`, more precisly the Almofire request is fired asynchronously.

So, the methods `Network()` and `tester()` are running simultaneously, but because `Network()` needs to fetch data first, `tester()` is faster and is executed first.

The proper way to execute `tester()` and `Network()` one after another would be:

```
   func CategoryNameFunc(Json: JSON, Count: Int)
    {
        for index in 0...Count-1 {
            let name = Json[index]["CATEGORY_NAME"].string
            CategoryNameArray.append(name!)
        }
        // run tester, AFTER you have the data.
        tester()
    }
```

Comment: I have a Table View where i want to list these categories. But it shows that Array is out of Range!

Comment: Try reloading the tableview after you fetch the data - insteaf of calling tester() in the method above, try calling: tableView.reloadData() (tableView is the reference to your tableView)